# add top menu into left panel in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, menu

I want to remove the top menu from header and include into left panel. How to I do that?. And also is there a way to do that without xml?

Comment: Top Navigation means categories from top menu?

Comment: top catagories menu...actually I want to show this menu vertically in the left panel.

Answer (score 1):

Check out directory `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/navigation/`, there are two files, `left.phtml` and `top.phtml`. One of them is top menu and another is left menu.

While it's technically possible to avoid using layouts (such as adding `left.phtml` code to `2columns-left.phtml`), it's strongly NOT advised. I would even go so far that I would call it a crime against the best Magento practices.